# Using ccnet to publish .net site

Tags: git, msbuild, publish, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to get a site from git to build and then publish using [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl). Looked at a few guides online and was able to get something that I think should work but every time it builds it succeeds but returns a message `Skipping unpublishable project` and doesn't publish anywhere. Here is what I have in the ccnet.config file currently.

```
  <project name="Site">
<workingDirectory>C:\Build\Site\Build</workingDirectory>
<artifactDirectory>C:\Build\Site\Publish</artifactDirectory>
<tasks Name="Clean">
  <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\Build\Site\Build</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>Site.csproj</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>
      /t:Publish
    </buildArgs>
    <timeout>900</timeout>
  </msbuild>
</tasks>   
  <sourceControlProvider type="git">
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe</executable>
    <repository>gitreporsitory</repository>
    <workingDirectory>c:\build\site\build</workingDirectory>
  </sourceControlProvider>
```

Comment: What happens in visual studio when you build with the publish configuration. This error seems to come from your project not cruise control.

Comment: Does the user that the cruise control service runs as have access to publish to the remote location?